# Inflating fragment through a fragment and passing arguments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-view

I was trying to inflate a same fragment through a fragment and passing arguments, its working but the arguments which are passed are applied on the previous fragment but not on the new fragment.

The fragment contains a TextView and a Spinner.

fragment class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    qust = b.getString("Question","");
    id = b.getInt("id");

    final connection con = (connection) getActivity();

    question = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.question);
    spinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    question.setText(qust);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),id,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (i!=0)
                con.inflate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

}
```

I am inflating a fragment when the user selects any item in the previous fragment spinner.

MainActivity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements connection {

    int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyFragments mF = new MyFragments();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("Question","Where are you?");
        b.putInt("id",R.array.planets_array);
        mF.setArguments(b);
        FragmentManager manage = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manage.beginTransaction();
        trans.add(R.id.root,mF,"frag");
        trans.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void inflate() {

        MyFragments f = new MyFragments();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("Question","what are you doing?");
        b.putInt("id",R.array.colours);
        f.setArguments(b);
        FragmentTransaction tran = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tran.add(R.id.root,f,"added");
        tran.commit();
    }
}
```

interface to communicate b/w fragments:

```
  public interface connection {

    void inflate();
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU26F.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that has been occurred, because you instantiate new fragment on 
your inflate() method without unique TAG. Set up unique TAG or use different add(@IdRes int containerViewId, Fragment fragment) instead.

Comment: Write me your task. What you want to get in the end ?